# Loop Through Array and Change Filter on OLAP Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm pretty new to VBA so I'm looking for some help on setting up a macro that will add the values from a specific range to an array and then loop through that array to update the filters on a pivot table. However not every value might be set. An example of this would be that only 4 values are set out of a 100 so it would only loop through it 4 times and update the filter with those 4 values. I have never worked with for loops before so any guidance on this would be extremely helpful.

My code so far:

```
Sub Update_Filters()

    Dim PortfolioCodes As Variant
    PortfolioCodes = Sheets("Configuration Sheet").Range("C7:C45").Value

    Sheets("List").PivotTables("List").PivotFields( _
        "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].[Portfolio Code]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].&[ABC1]", "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].&[ABC2]", _
        "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].&[XYZ1]", "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].&[XYZ2]")
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get it, you want your procedure to show the data for all 4 values at the same time or filter 1 at a time and do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the two possible answers to your question:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Update_Filters()

    'this code will filter one portfolio code at a time
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration Sheet")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim PortfolioCodes As Variant
        PortfolioCodes = .Range("C7:C" & LastRow).Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(PortfolioCodes) To UBound(PortfolioCodes)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").PivotTables("List").PivotFields( _
        "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].[Portfolio Code]").VisibleItemsList = _
            Array("[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].&[" & PortfolioCodes(i) & "]")
        'some code
    Next i

End Sub
Sub Update_FiltersALL()

    'This code will filter all the portfolio codes in your range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration Sheet")

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim i As Long
        i = 1

        ReDim PortfolioCodes(1 To LastRow - 6) As String
        Dim C As Range
        For Each C In .Range("C7:C" & LastRow)
            If Not IsEmpty(C) Then
                PortfolioCodes(i) = "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].&[" & C.Value & "]"
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next C
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").PivotTables("List").PivotFields( _
    "[Portfolio].[Portfolio Code].[Portfolio Code]").VisibleItemsList = PortfolioCodes

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the second version of the code you provided which updates all, however it's throwing a subscript out of range error. Is there something that I'm over looking?

Comment: @Gil when trying to filter? might be some empty values on the range? or some codes which aren't on the olap?

Comment: Yes there are empty values in the range which is why I want the range to stop reading at the point where the next cell is empty

Comment: @Gil try my edit.. it will ignore empty cells and loop only to the last row (will ignore empty cells that might be in between your range)

Comment: I'm getting a new error "Compile Error: Constant expression required", which is highlighting the LastRow in Dim PortfolioCodes(1 To LastRow - 6) As String

Comment: @Gil sorry! change `Dim`for `ReDim` like my code now.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!