# Excel Slicer connected to a Power Pivot - Select multiple slicer items

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot, slicers

I'm trying to make a report form that will ask what month and year you want the report to show. However, there is a specific pivot table that uses a four-year range to show trends data.

However, all the pivot tables on my workbook are connected through Power Pivot/Data Model. [Using this source here](https://eriksvensen.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/setting-selected-item-in-a-slicer-connected-to-a-power-pivot-table-via-vba/), I was able to easily change slicers for single-items only.

An example that's working:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Month2").VisibleSlicerItemsList = "[Calendar].[Month].&[" & frmGen.cbMonth.Text & "]"
```

But when I used a loop to replace multiple selections in the slicer, I've encountered an error after it's done looping all of the selection, with an error '28': Out of stack space.

```
    For i = 0 To 3 Step 1
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Year").VisibleSlicerItemsList(i + 1) = "[Calendar].[Month].&[" & frmGen.txtYear.Text - 3 + i & "]"
    Next
```

Since there's already four that was selected on the slicer, it should have been able to replace it, which is also shown when I added the code onto the watch window. But it always show that error after the loop, even if I lower the loop count.

Is there another way of selecting multiple items in a slicer that's connected through Power Pivot?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59055367/7558682) it might help you.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize I could just update one of the pivot tables and the slicer will sync it up with the other pivot tables as well, thanks for the link got mine to work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Damian for providing a clue to my problem, I simply had to update one of the pivot tables that's linked to the slicer and it updated the other pivots just fine.

```
For i = 0 To 3 Step 1
    ar(i) = "[Calendar].[Year].&[" & frmGen.txtYear.Text - 3 + i & "]"
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("pg2").PivotTables("pvtPg2_SPARK").PivotFields("[Calendar].[Year].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = ar
```